# How to grant EXECUTE Stored Procedure for a user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grant EXECUTE Stored Procedure for a user in cPanel(the latest version 11.28.60), but it does not work. Should I create the Stored Procedure before grant the EXECUTE privilege? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create the procedure first. The procedure has to exist before you can grant permissions on it.